# JSF 2.0: StateHolder vs. Serializable?

Tags: jsf, serialization, jsf-2

JSF has a special state-saving code that expects objects to implement `StateHolder` apart from the common `Serializable` approach. However, I just had a look at `AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl` class bundled with Mojarra 2.0.2. Instead using `StateHolder`, it is simply implementing `Serializable` and this works ok.

The thread at http://old.nabble.com/Serializable-UIcomponents-td19471884.html seems to state that going with `Serializable` should be avoided, but what are the detailed rules with this? It seems that, when object doesn't have any children (to notify of state changes), implementing Serializable is ok.

When is it ok to use `Serializable` and when not? It takes less code with `Serializable` as it is automated...